# PushKit notification arriving after call has ended

Tags: ios, swift, callkit, pushkit

I have an application that implements PushKit and CallKit. The scenario in which the problem occurs is as follow:

Device A initiates a call, sending a PushKit notification to Device B.
Device B has no internet connection, and therefore does not receive the call.
Device A ends the call.
Device B connects to the internet after some time.
Device B receives the PushKit notification that Device A sent earlier and displays CallKit Incoming Call UI.

As you can see, Device B will display CallKit Incoming Call UI even after Device A ended the call.

How to prevent Device B from receiving the incoming call?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In iOS 13 you must report an incoming call before you leave the PushKit completion handler, otherwise your app will be blocked from receiving further PushKit pushes.  Obviously, this is a slight problem when you have a case such as you described where the call no longer exists.

This scenario, and others, were discussed in an [Apple Developer Forums thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/117939)

The specific advice for your case is:

> - While you must report an incoming call immediately, you are still free to decide  the call has failed and tell the system later, asynchronously. To do this, call reportCallWithUUID:endedAtDate:reason:. This will tear down the incoming call UI even if the user has not answered the call.
> - If the user is particularly fast at tapping the accept call button, or if the network conditions are poor or there is otherwise a lot of latency, then you should simply wait until the necessary handshakes are complete before calling fulfill on the CXAnswerCallAction. To the user, it simply appears that the call is taking some time to connect, which is a common experience even with standard phone calls.
> - Note that the system takes a few seconds for the incoming call UI to animate in, during which the app has the opportunity to complete this handshake, so this will only have a user-visible impact if it takes a significant time for the handshake to complete.

So, what you need to do is report the call, then when you determine that the call is no longer valid (which shouldn't take long at all), immediately end the call.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I’ve come across apns-expiration parameter which is specified in the Push Notification payload. When set to 0, the push notifications is discarded when it is not delivered immediately. Will that help me to solve my problem?

Comment: It will definitely help, but it isn't a 100% solution. You still have to handle the case where the caller starts a call and then immediately ends it leading to a race condition where the app receives a push for a call that is no longer valid.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply

Comment: Yes, the expiration parameter must be 0, but I've seen that it isn't really 0. I think that it corresponds to at least 10 seconds. You can easily test it: activate the airplane mode on device B, make a call with device A and hang up soon after, wait 10 seconds and deactivate the airplane mode; you will receive the call on device B. Repeat the test increasing the waiting time of a few seconds until you won't receive the call.

Answer (score 1):

You should send the end-call signal through a PushKit notification so that, as soon as device B reconnects, it will receive both the start-call and end-call notifications.

Comment: This will cause didReceivePush to be called twice, when Device B reconnects. Wouldn’t that create a race condition?

Comment: This also won't work because you must report a call for each PushKit notification or your app will be blocked from receiving them.

Comment: Yes, it will cause didReceivePush to be called twice, but with the first one you report the call and with the second one you just end the call. You have to send two pushes with different content to distinguish them. @Paulw11 As far as I've been able to test it, while there's an active call (i.e. you've already reported a call) you don't have to report a new call whenever you receive a PushKit notification.